# 5.7 Hemi coolant leak

Tags: jeep, coolant-leak

I have a 05 Jeep limited with the 5.7 hemi.  I have a coolant leak coming from the backside of the engine, and it’s dripping off the fire-wall, I notice there is a house coming up with a clamp.   Should I be worried abt a headgasket?  There is no bubbles, and it’s not over heating, I also checked the oil cap for sludge.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If it's coming off of the firewall, it's probably the heater core or coolant hoses to the heater core which is leaking.

Comment: Paulster2  that’s what I think it is, but I can’t get to it with out taking the intake manifold off.   And it doesn’t have a heater core in it, I took it out and put a new one in so I’m having to run new everything.   But I think where it was plugged it got back pressure and come loose.  It’s not a lot of leakage just enough to see the dripping and notice the smell.  But thanks for the comment

Comment: You might be able to stick a cell phone up in the area to see where it's leaking from. Just take a video of the area until you find what's wet. Might be worth a try to see.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your hose and clamp .It might tee off to the heater on your vehcile .It does on our chrysler 300c .The tee is made of rubbishy plastic and does crack .Result is coolant loss which the temp guage only temperorly responds to .ie it goes up and then down because there is no water to sense anymore .For me and Barb it meant engine rebuild due to dropped valve seats .